# Does CPU Vertical Segment: Embedded mean that it can not be swapped?

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-core-i7, embedded, processor-socket

Im interested with CPU replace in laptop, but something made me think a lot. I want to ask you simply if there is a socket defined, how can a processor be embedded? Does it work like it can be embedded but also putted in socket or whatever, Im talking about the i7-3610QE, can please anyone who knows something about cpus check it for me, since im a big idiot in this

Comment: "how can a processor be embedded?" - Processors sold for embedded solutions are typically soldered to the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded in this case is Intel talk for a CPU can be used in kiosks, industrial tablets, etc. It will be available for a longer period so that manufacturers can be sure they have spare parts.

It has some different characterics too, see this comparison on [ARK](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=65711,64899) between the i7-3610QE and i7-3610QM

As an example one difference is the Embedded is vPro compatible, the Mobile isn't.

In general you need to check the laptop manufacturer website to see which CPU's are supported. Even if the QE fits physically it might not work with your motherboard and BIOS / UEFI!

Comment: Thank you for your answear, but may I ask you also, I have Toshiba Satellite C850 19Q and the main problem is that I can't find compatibility list and the name of motherboard either

Comment: Yeah that doesn't look good, I can't find any information either. Maybe try contacting Toshiba support, that's the only option I can think of.